# WPF and Json Deserializer with multiple items

Tags: c#, wpf, json, datacontractserializer

I'm trying to deserialize a give json string that has multiple device names and Ip addresses. The code that I am trying to work out is below.

```
var rawData = "[{\"Name\" : \"xbox\", \"IP\" : \"192.100.14.160\"} ,{\"Name\" : \"ps3\", \"IP\" : \"192.100.14.131\"}]";
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(deviceCollection));
MemoryStream sr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(rawData));
ControllerCollection pat = serializer.ReadObject(sr) as ControllerCollection;
sr.Close();

[DataContract]
public class ControllerCollection
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Controller> Controllers { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Controller
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string IP { get; set; }
}
```

When I do this I get a null value for the ControllerCollection.
Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Use JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize() as it is simpler and doesn't need to mark DataContract. It is in System.Web.Extensions assembly. Here is the code that works. List<Controller> controllers = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Controller>>(rawData);

Comment: @Nirvan DataContractJsonSerializer  doesn't need [DataContract] either. His problem was the JSON is incorrect.

Comment: @Nirvan the JSON in the question is not the JSON notation for an object of type ControllerCollection. See my answer for the proper structure.

Comment: @cheedep, Yes I just saw that. Thats why I deleted my comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rawData = "{\"Controllers\": [{\"Name\" : \"xbox\", \"IP\" : \"192.100.14.160\"} ,{\"Name\" : \"ps3\", \"IP\" : \"192.100.14.131\"}]}";
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ControllerCollection), new Type[] {typeof(Controller)});
MemoryStream sr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(rawData));
//sr.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
ControllerCollection pat = (ControllerCollection)serializer.ReadObject(sr);
sr.Close();
```

Your Json string is in incorrect format.